# Using Selenium Python to get value embedded in react-text code

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mSZ6.jpg)I'm using Selenium in Python to crawl some data from Internet for my works.
However, I can't manage to get the tel number (i.e. 04 81 68 30 45) from this HTML source code:

```
'<a class="_2sNbI ObuDQ GXQkc _2BP2c" href="tel:0481683045" title="Contact le vendeur" ><!-- react-text: 619 -->04 81 68 30 45<!-- /react-text --></a>'
```

I tried that code but it does not work with react-text code. I got an empty string

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.leboncoin.fr/locations/1107498086.htm/')

try:
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="_2sPVF"]//button')
    elem.click()
except:
    pass

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="_28rnK"]/a')
tel = elem.text
print('Contact:', tel)
```

If anyone have any idea how to do that, I will be very grateful.

***Thank for JeffC's answer, the problem is resolved, it is turned out that there are 5 hidden elements in that xpath (the tel number is the 4th one).

Comment: Can you post the code you're using and what result it's giving you?

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as the code you have provided still does not allow us to replicate the problem you are having. You should also edit the post tags to specify which language you are using with Selenium (Python in this case).

Comment: I tried element.text but it showed an empty string. I also tried get_attribute("innerHTML") and get_attribute("outerHTML") but both don't give me the string containing the tel number that I want

Comment: Are you sure the locator is locating the exact element you are looking for? It's possible that there are multiple elements found and it's returning the value for the first one which is not the one you want. You can print `len(driver.find_elements_*()` and see how many there are or you can use `$x()` in the dev console of the browser.

Comment: I updated my code in the question and added an image of the tel number that I need to get.

Comment: You didn't respond to my comment. Also, the HTML that you posted doesn't include the HTML that you reference in your locator so we can't check it. The page you linked doesn't have the phone number that you are referring to either. Please update your question with valid info.

Comment: @JeffC: Thank you, I used your len(driver.find_elements_*() and found out that there are 5 elements in there. The tel number is the 4th element. Sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: I posted an answer based on our conversation so the question isn't left unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

In situations like this, I generally investigate the page and ensure that the locator I'm using is finding the element that I want. I generally go about this using the dev console in Chrome and using `$$()` to test CSS selectors and `$x()` to test XPaths.

As you found, the element you were looking for was not the one returned because it was not unique on the page and was not the first of the collection of elements that matched the locator.

Comment: The preface to your answers e.g. `Just posting this ... so the question doesn't get left unanswered` are typically considered as _noise_ as StackOverflow standards. Consider focusing on the Answer part only.